# Putting my flight simulator into motion. Need advice on actuator placement.

Tags: geometry

I'm stumped. The math for this is way beyond me. I hope someone can help.
In the pic, the right side is the platform arc and the left is the actuator arm arc. the arcs are perpendicular to one another The arm is 6" from center to center with a 6" connecting rod attached to the hole on the end. The platform is 9" from center to the attaching point of the other end of the connecting rod. I am trying to determine what the x-y location of the actuator arm's connecting rod hole should be with the arm in the level position. The goal being to make the platform's vertical movement as directly proportional to the arm's degree of rotation as possible. All measurements are imperial. The maximum rotation of the arm is 45 degree up and down off of center. The connecting rod has ball joints on each end. 
is this solvable with the supplied information? 
[image]

Comment: I can hardly understand a thing you're asking. I cannot even understand the diagram-- one circle says *Front* while the other says *Side*. But they cannot be depictions of the same object from different angles because you have measurements between the two circles.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a requirement for more information.

**

Sorry, i am not following your statement. But as we are dealing with a mechanism, we must take into account Grashof's Law.

See for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuOlQUauvY4

After seeing this video, please update your drawing showing top, middle and bottom position of your ACTUATOR ARM, and the corresponding positions of your PLATFORM.

What I understand is that the left ACTUATOR ARM is 6" and can move +/- 45degrees from horizontal position.
Attached to it we have a CONNECTING ROD which is also 6".
And this CONNECTING ROD is connected to the PLATFORM disc which has a radius of 9".

Correct?

What's the distance between both centers (ACTUATOR ARM and PLATFORM DISC)?

Please explain better the following:

`The goal being to make the platform's vertical movement as directly proportional to the arm's degree of rotation as possible.`

Comment: Thaank you for the video. I can see where the confusion comes in. The drawing is deceptive. My apologies.
Here is a video of what I am doing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVDGjfTJ4C8
So assuming the platform's connecting rod attachment point is considered the origin point of the x,y plane, where on the x,y plane should the actuator's connecting rod point be located. Do the numbers in the picture provide enough information with the inclusion of the video?

Comment: I will try to find out something during the week. If I post something, it will be next Saturday.